# Get elements by class name with Elm.Browser.Dom

Tags: dom, elm, classname

I know I can get an `Element` by id with [Browser.Dom.getElement](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/browser/latest/Browser-Dom#getElement).

But how can I get a `List Element` by classname?

Comment: Could you describe why you need that function, what is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Usually there are better ways to solve UI scenarios than querying DOM. Perhaps by modeling the state such that no DOM queries are required.

Answer (score 2):

As of Elm 0.19, the *browser* package doesn't expose any other helper functions to query the DOM. The [`getElement` function itself is directly calling a kernel function](https://github.com/elm/browser/blob/1.0.2/src/Browser/Dom.elm#L356-L358):

```
getElement : String -> Task Error Element
getElement =
    Elm.Kernel.Browser.getElement
```

Depending on what you want to do specifically, you might want to write a JavaScript function that queries the elements, reads the interesting bits, and makes the result accessible to your Elm application through [the ports system](https://evancz.gitbooks.io/an-introduction-to-elm/content/interop/ports.html).

For instance, take a look at the [*elm-dom-ports* package](https://github.com/paulstatezny/elm-dom-ports) for inspiration. It exposes `document.querySelectorAll()` function as a port and you can catch its result by subscribing to `querySelectorAllResponse`.